# Why does ipsec want me to disable redirects?

Tags: ipsec

I've just configured a vpn connection (l2tp), but when I run `ipsec verify` I get:

```
$ ipsec verify
...
 NETKEY: Testing XFRM related proc values
         ICMP default/send_redirects                [NOT DISABLED]

  Disable /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/send_redirects or NETKEY will cause act on or cause sending of bogus ICMP redirects!

         ICMP default/accept_redirects              [NOT DISABLED]

  Disable /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/accept_redirects or NETKEY will cause act on or cause sending of bogus ICMP redirects!

         XFRM larval drop                           [OK]
```

Can you explain in simple words what that means, and what will happen if I won't disable them?

Answer (score 1):

For *send_redirects* you can find an answer in the [Libreswan FAQ](https://libreswan.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_recommended_to_disable_send_redirects_in_.2Fproc.2Fsys.2Fnet_.3F):

> Let's say you have a VPN server in a cloud that you use with your
> phone. Your phone will setup an IPsec VPN and all its traffic is
> encrypted and send to the cloud instance, which decrypts it and sends
> it on the internet, using SNAT. Replies it receives are encrypted and
> send to your phone.
>
> Your phone will send the VPN server an encrypted packet. The server
> receives it on eth0 (its only interface!) and decrypts it. The
> decrypted packet is then ready to get routed. The server looks which
> interface it should send the packet to. It is destined to go out eth0.
> Since the packet came in via eth0 and would go out via eth0, the
> server concludes there clearly must be a better path not involving
> itself, since it is going out the same interface. It has no idea the
> packet arrived encrypted and got decrypted.
>
> This is why we recommend disabling "send_redirects" in
> /etc/sysctl.conf using

Maybe the [Introduction to strongSwan](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling) is a little bit clearer here:

> If the VPN gateway is not the default gateway of the LAN, ICMP
> redirects might get returned to hosts if they send traffic destined
> for the remote hosts/subnets to the VPN gateway, directing them to the
> default gateway of the LAN (which probably doesn't work and otherwise
> might get that traffic out unencrypted). To avoid this, disable
> sending such ICMP messages by setting net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects
> and net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects to 0 (if the latter is not
> set before the interface comes up, also set the option for the
> individual interface, i.e. net.ipv4.conf..send_redirects).

For *accept_redirects* I would assume just good networking practice. Since your VPN gateway should know all local routes, any ICMP redirect would be bogus and should be ignored.